# LWUIT: Can not set Tabs icons

Tags: icons, lwuit, lwuit-tabs

I'm using lwuit resource editor to design my app forms.
I have a tab and i want to set icons but after i select them and press OK i got just null, nothing happened.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in LWUIT 1.5 related to that, it was only resolved in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com). Short of migrating to Codename One your other option is to set the icons in code.

Comment: Thank you, yes i decided to completely do my app in code and use resource editor just for designing the theme.